# Computing the limit $a_n = i^{n!}$ as $n \to \infty$

Tags: limits, complex-numbers

I am trying to compute the limit $a_n = i^{n!}$ as $n \to \infty$, but I am apparently missing some important rule when computing the power of a complex number, as the following doesn't make any sense: In general for $z, w\in \mathbb{C}: z^w = \exp(w\log(z))$. Now $w = n!$ and $z = i$. Hence $i^{n!} = \exp(n!\log(i)) = \exp(n!(\ln(|i|) + i(\mathrm{Arg}(i) + 2\pi k))) = \exp(n!(0 + i((\pi/2) + 2\pi k))) = \exp(n!)\exp(i((\pi/2) + 2\pi k))$ so that $i^{n!} = \exp(n!)(\cos((\pi/2) + 2\pi k) + i\sin((\pi/2) + 2\pi k) = \exp(n!)i \to \infty, n\to \infty$, but $|i| = 1$.

All tips are appreciated!

Comment: You have overcomplicated the problem. In this case, as $n!$ is an integer, it's the usual meaning of "power", i.e. $i^{n!}$ is the product of $n!$ $i$'s.

Comment: hint: show $n!$ divisible by $4$.

Comment: @WhatsUp Yeah I agree. I just now realized where I had made the mistake. See my answer for more details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For $4 \leq n \in \mathbb N$ you got that $n!$ is divisible by $4$, since $n! = n \cdot (n - 1) \cdot \ldots \cdot 4 \cdot \ldots \cdot 1$. Hence for such $n \in \mathbb N$ you can always find an $m \in \mathbb N$ such that $n! = 4m$. Thus,
$$\mathrm i^{n!} = \mathrm i^{4m} = (\mathrm i^4)^m = 1^m = 1. \qquad (n \geq 4)$$
Thus we get that $\lim_{n \to \infty} \mathrm i^{n!} = 1$.

Answer (score 1):

I really don't know how this is possible, but I somehow thought that $\exp(ab) = \exp(a)\exp(b)$, when in fact $\exp(a + b) = \exp(a)\exp(b)$, for $a, b \in \mathbb{C}$. So that is the root of the error.